# Has the definition of vertical scaling changed - and if so what do we call it

Tags: terminology

15 years ago when we were figuring out how to scale SQL databases to huge systems, we used the term Horizontal scaling to mean split up your tables so that the same schema existed on multiple machines - and Vertical scaling to mean put some tables on machine A, and some on machine B.

Recent definitions (here and on Google) seem to have morphed in that Vertical scaling is now defined as throwing more hardware on your single database.

So what is the term for "split up your single database into multiple databases such that some such that you have different tables / schemas living on your various DBs"?

Comment: That sounds like partitioning. See for example: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: Hmm, vertical scaling always meant "make the box your database runs on bigger" (more CPUs, more disks, more RAM) to me. Horizontal scaling was always about adding more servers and duplicate the data across servers (think "cluster"). If you distribute the actual content (one part on server a, one part on server b) that' typically called "sharding".

Comment: The question.  If I have a DB with ( say) customer, customer orders, customer OrderItems, Shipments, shipment items  etc.  I partition by putting the Shipments and Shipment Items in a new database.  what do you call it?  15 years ago we called it Vertical Partitioning.  What would you call it today?